# Box with same vertical height, even when empty

Tags: spacing, boxes

I'm trying to draw a vertical box around one or more lines of text (for a field in a pre-filled form), but some of the fields may be empty and in these cases, the box should be the same vertical height as when there is only one line (or even just one character) of content within the box.

I am currently defining a `\field` command for this, like so:

```
\newcommand{\field}[1]{
    \framebox[\textwidth][l]{        
        \parbox[l]{0.96\textwidth}{
            \raggedright #1 \addvspace{0.1\baselineskip}
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me a 'missing item' error because `\addvspace` isn't in vertical mode.  If I add a `\par` to fix this, the box has too much vertical padding after the last line of text.  If I remove the `\addvspace` entirely then the box is not tall enough when it contains no text.

Could someone please suggest the best way of creating a box, the full width of the page, that is a minimum of one line of text high (even when empty) but can expand to contain multiple lines of text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically one would include a `\strut` at the beginning. Note also that you have some spurious spaces in your macro definition (you need some strategic placements of `%`). See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) I'm also guessing your use of `.96\textwidth` results from some overfull `\hbox`es. You can adjust this width to fit perfectly within the text block as well...

Here's perhaps something that you're after:

```
\newcommand{\field}[1]{%
  \noindent%
  \framebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
      \raggedright\strut#1%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Here is its use in a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\field}[1]{%
  \noindent%
  \framebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
      \raggedright\strut#1%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\field{Some test}

\field{}

\field{I'm trying to draw a vertical box around one or more lines of
  text (for a field in a pre-filled form), but some of the fields may
  be empty and in these cases, the box should be the same vertical 
  height as when there is only one line (or even just one character) 
  of content within the box.}
\end{document}
```

Depending on your usage, you may also consider ending with a `\strut`, allowing for adequate space if the last line has no descender.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for - many thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have a list inside this environment without top spacing. I've been using `enumitem` to embed a list as 

```
\field{%
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\end{itemize}
}
```
But I still get a top vertical spacing. Is it because of something I didn't understand in the `field` environment?

Comment: @Werner I have part of my answer: it seems to depend on the environment since outside the environment I do not have the top spacing. After some trials, it seems to be because of the `\strut`. What will it break to remove it?

Comment: I have my answer again… And empty box won't have the desired height. So I ended with an `if/else` clause with the `strut` only if there is no list given.